# The connection was not close

Tags: razor-pages, .net-6.0

I have this error if I try to refresh many times the page,

I'm using razor pages .net6

I really don't know what to do to pass this.

[image]

Comment: if you check `con.State` after `con.Close()`,will it be closed?

Comment: i know why, what stupid thing, i used private static SqlConnection con = new(ConnectionString);